# SQLite - don't work autoincrement

Tags: android, sqlite

I create database file from **SQLite Expert Personal**. 
I use this database in my app on Android, but **autoincrement** don't work.

This **DDL** of one table from this database -

```
    CREATE TABLE [dn_events] (
  [id] [INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT], 
  [action_id] INTEGER, 
  [action_type_id] INTEGER, 
  [action_title] TEXT, 
  [action_run] INTEGER, 
  [action_date] INTEGER, 
  [action_rating] DOUBLE, 
  [action_public] INTEGER, 
  [action_node] TEXT, 
  [action_price_total] DOUBLE, 
  [car_id] INTEGER, 
  [action_remind_run] INTEGER, 
  [action_remind_date] INTEGER, 
  [updated_at] INTEGER, 
  [fuelling_type_id] INTEGER, 
  [fuelling_azs_id] INTEGER, 
  [fuelling_liters_amount] DOUBLE, 
  [fuelling_liters_price] DOUBLE, 
  [fuelling_is_full_tank] INTEGER, 
  [fuelling_is_forgot_prev] INTEGER, 
  [fuelling_azs_title] CHAR, 
  [event_type_id] INTEGER, 
  [event_issuer] TEXT, 
  [event_type_title] TEXT, 
  [remind_on] INTEGER, 
  [method] INTEGER, 
  [longitude] DOUBLE, 
  [latitude] DOUBLE, 
  [geo_id] INTEGER, 
  [repair_due_accident] INTEGER, 
  [action_price_total_rub] DOUBLE, 
  [repair_sto_name] TEXT, 
  [repair_job_price] DOUBLE);
```

When I insert one event to table if I dont set id in manual I get null in database

Comment: can you post the query you used for creating the table in the program.

Comment: No, I cant do it, becouse database file has static data

Comment: The brackets prevent the `autoincrement` from working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a similar problem with the same tool right now.

There is a GUI to select the primary key but the autoincrement box is not selectable.

This is because I was using INT

With INTEGER it allows the autoincrement

Answer (score 2):

Remove the brackets around the data type

```
[id] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
```

#### [SQLfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/ee09c/1)

Comment: I use program for create database - and I cant remove this brackets. http://dl2.joxi.net/drive/0004/0191/303295/150209/2467ac939d.png

Comment: The column type is just `integer`. You define the key and auto-increment elsewhere in your tool.